# Highlight the lowest price

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Get and highlight the lowest price between decimals within a `foreach`.

### The scenario

I'm comparing various products prices between some markets. The result is displayed in a HTML's `table`. The last row of this table contains the total value which is the sum by each product's price of each market.

For example:

```
                 Market 1    Market 2  
 Xbox 360        US$119,00   US$125,00 
 Playstation 3   US$129,00   US$119,00 
 Total           US$248,00   US$244,00
```

The code behind on the View is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Collection.Products.DistinctBy(p => p.id))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>@item.name</p>
        </td>

        @foreach (var market in Model.Markets)
        {
            <td>
                @foreach (var product in Model.Collection.Products.Where
                    (p => p.productId == item.productId && 
                     p.marketId == market.id))
                {
                    <p>@product.price</p>
                }
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}

<tr>
    @foreach (var market in @Model.Markets)
    {
        <td class="total">
            @{
                decimal totalValue = 
                    Model.Collection.GetTotalPrice(market.marketId);
            }

            @if (totalValue == 0)
            {
                <h2>Unavailable</h2>
            }
            else
            {
                <h2>US$@totalValue</h2>
            }
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

So far, so good. Now comes the problem: I want to highlight the **lowest price between the markets (lowest total price)** — how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean the lowest total price, or the lowest price in every column / row?

Comment: I see no association between the product & the market in your example? Also you need to elaborate on "highlight the lowest price" of what? Each individual market? Each product?

Comment: @dutch Oh, the lowest total price. Sorry about this.

Comment: "Association", in this case is relative. Take a look on my update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just pull the lowest price out and use it as a benchmark. This example sets a `lowest` class on the `<p>` tag of the price if it's `<=` the lowest product price for that particular market

```
@foreach (var market in Model.Markets)
{
    @{ 
        var marketProducts = Model.Collection.Products.Where(p => p.productId == item.productId && p.marketId == market.id).ToList();
        var lowestMarketPrice = marketProducts.Min(p => p.price);
    }
    <td>
        @foreach (var product in marketProducts)
        {
            <p @(product.price <= lowestMarketPrice ? "class=lowest" : "")>@product.price</p>
        }
    </td>
}
```

---

Based on your clarification, here is how you can highlight the lowest *total* across *any* market

```
@{ 
    var marketTotals = Model.Markets.ToDictionary(m => m.marketId, m => Model.Collection.GetTotalPrice(m.marketId));
    var lowestTotal = marketTotals.Min(t => t.Value);
}
@foreach (var price in marketTotals)
{
    <td @(price.Value <= lowestTotal ? "class=total-lowest" : "class=total")>
        <h2>@{ price.Value == 0 ? "Unavailable" : String.Format("US${0}", price.Value) }</h2>
    </td>
}
```

Comment: Does this make sense? I ask this because one product can be more expensive, but an other one can be cheaper — I think your logic aren't right basing on this philosophy. To better comprehension of this commentary, take a look on my last update — I changed the example to better illustrate.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge it's really up to you to decide which logic works best, I am answering your question based on the fact you want to highlight the "*lowest price per market*" which I am confident this code will do.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge you are asking for lowest price highlighting

Comment: I'm not asking you about the *"lowest price per market"*, but on the *"lowest price between the markets (lowest total price)"*.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge well your question wasn't really clear in fairness. Ok so you are looking for the lowest total of all products across all markets then?

Comment: @James You're right — at first I wasn't clear enough, sorry for this. And yes, I'm looking for the **lowest TOTAL price**, independent of which market is. In our case, the lowest price that I want to highlight is `244`, from `Market 2` because the sum of its products is the cheaper/lowest.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the minimal prices before rendering the output:

```
@{
var products = Model.Collection.Products.DistinctBy(p => p.id);
decimal[] minimalPrices = new decimal[products.Length];
@for(int i = 0; i < products.Length; i++))
{
  decimal min = Decimal.MaxValue;
  @foreach (var market in Model.Markets)
  {
    //..compute price and compare to min        
  }
  minimalPrices[i] = min;
}
}
```

.....
in rendering

```
if( price == minimalPrices[i])
   highlight it
```

Comment: Hello, @qub1n! You understood my problem, hehe. By the way, there's not a `Length` property for `var products`.